# Modify the shade of a node depending on node attributes in igraph?

Tags: r, igraph

So I currently have a social network graph that I created in igraph. It has 50 nodes with 80 unique connections. Each node has 1 attribute: 'A' which is a random number between 1 and 10. Is there a way to set the color of the nodes as one thing (red) and then modify the shade depending on the value of 'A'?

```
V(net)$color=V(net)$A
V(net)$color=gsub(1,"red",V(net)$color) 
V(net)$color=gsub(2,"pink",V(net)$color)
```

I currently use a form of this code but ideally I want something so that the higher the value of 'A' is, the darker the shade of red it becomes.So when V(net)$A == 10, it's a really dark red but when V(net)$A == 1, it becomes an almost white, light pink. Is there a code to do this without manually plugging in the different shades into the above code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a base R function to generate shades of a color. Clearly there are such functions and palettes in various R packages. But we may instead use the following

```
myShade <- function(i, n = 10) {
  upper <- c(110, 0, 0)
  lower <- c(255, 210, 210)
  shade <- round(lower + (i - 1) * (upper - lower) / (n - 1))
  paste(c("#", sprintf("%02s", as.hexmode(shade))), collapse = "")
}

barplot(table(letters[1:10]), col = sapply(1:10, myShade))
```

[image]

Here `i` is an integer from 1 to 10 and `n` is the total number of shades. More generally, however, you could set, e.g., `n = 1` and `i` to any real number from [0,1], which would give you a lot of shades (not infinitely many though, due to rounding in `shade`).

Then `upper` and `lower` correspond to dark red and light red, respectively, in RGB format. By altering those you may straightforwardly change your palette. Then `shade` does the interpolation and the last line constructs a hex code, e.g.,

```
myShade(5)
# [1] "#bf7575"
```

Then I guess you could do

```
V(net)$color <- sapply(V(net)$A, myShade) # or as.numeric(V(net)$A) if V(net)$A is a character
```